# How do I merge duplicate rows and change all False values into True where True is the value in the duplicate rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

So I have a dataframe that has plenty of duplicates but the problem is that they are like this-

```
  Color  ID
1 False  123456
2 True   123456
3 False  0987
4 False  0987
5 True   0987
```

In this example I want to combine all duplicate ID's and make everything `True` but only if there is a `True` in the column `color`.

This is my expected output

```
       ID  Color
0     987   True
1  123456   True
```

But I want to do it for EVERY column, not just one (in this case `Color`).

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in pyspark:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy('ID').agg(
     f.max(f.col('Color')).alias('Color')
)
```

Or alternatively:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy('ID').agg(
     f.max(f.when(f.col('Color'), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))).cast('boolean').alias('Color')
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out on my own but it's basically the same thing that you posted.

Answer (score 2):

We have `any`

```
out=df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).Color.any()
out
Out[55]: 
       ID  Color
0     987   True
1  123456   True
```

Comment: Ok. How can I do that for all columns now?

Comment: could you show your expected output 
for a representative example? @Ravaal

Comment: I'm assuming this is a PySpark DF error but it doesn't accept `as_index=False` or `.any()`. Probably not your problem though

Comment: I think this answer shows ```pandas``` solution, and not ```pyspark``` ;)

Comment: I know. I would prefer a PySpark solution but if I can't get that I'll have to collect all of the data and that is going to take a while

Comment: I added ```pyspark``` option.